# Getting only the ID of latest tweet using CURL

Tags: php, curl, twitter

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/nafhameducation.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$latest_tweet = curl_exec($ch);
$latest_tweet_id = $latest_tweet[0]->id_str;
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm using this code to get the ID of the latest tweet on my time line, However $latest_tweet_id returns an empty string, any idea why it's not getting what I need?

Comment: If you would actually log errors and warnings, PHP would have told you where it starts to not work any longer. Do so and check your error log.

Comment: Hey the API is documented! Wow: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline <-- many parameters, for example the `count` - how cool is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $latest_tweet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Curl returns text.  Turn up your error reporting, btw, you should have been getting PHP errors, trying to access a string as an object.

Also, in debugging this, it would have been useful to `var_dump($latest_tweet);` after line 3 -- that should have made it clear that the type of $latest_tweet was not an object.